# get files back from deployed website on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-hub

I want to get files of website back  which I have deployed on azure. Is there any way to download or get that files from azure ?

Comment: any updates? are you able to download the files from Azure now?

Comment: yeah,use filezilla software and then you will able to download it@FredHan-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use FTP for that. Use [this search link](https://www.google.by/search?client=opera&q=azure+web+sites+ftp&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could access Azure website files (under /site/wwwroot directory) via FTP using your deployment credentials. You could find (or set) deployment credentials by going to **App Deployment>Deployment credentials** in Azure portal.

[image]

Besides, [Kudu Console tool](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) that gives us both command line and file browser access to sites, you could download website files via Kudu Console tool.

[image]